# Why does adding an ImageButton to a selectable ListView Item make the ListView un-selectable whereas a regular Button does not?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got a ListView and an Adapter to handle click events:

This is the Layout for the "Row" Item in the ListView:

(When enabling the ImageButton in this row Layout the entire ListView Item becomes unselectable, while you can select the ImageButton,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/clocklistbackgroundnopadding"
    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timer_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="29sp" />

    <!--
         ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/timer_delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:src="@drawable/clocklistdetaildisclosure2" /
    -->

    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:maxHeight="90dp"
        android:maxWidth="90dp"
        android:minWidth="50dp"
        android:padding="4dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="21sp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

however the regular Button can be added without any problem with both the button and the ListView Item being selectable.

Comment: Do you mean that you add the ImageButton or that you replace the Button with the ImageButton?

Comment: Either produces the same result, the presence of the ImageButton in the ListView Item always makes it (the Row) unselectable.

Answer (score 0):

Add below property in your relative layout

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants
```

and you will get click event on list item and image button as well.